# Passing output / variable of task A to task B using nx affected

Tags: nrwl-nx

I'm using the `nx affected` command to lint, test, build and deploy my projects.

Now I'd like to add a smoke test that relies on the deployment URL of the deploy task

```
nx affected --targets=test,build,deploy,smoke
```

Using Netlify, I'm getting the deployment URL as JSON, which I like to pass on to the smoke test target within the context of the current application.

Is there something Nx offers out of the box like an application context aware variable storage?